# How can I display own Events in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to measure my application, which is very performance sensitive.

To do so I would like to know if there is an option in the Chrome dev tools or in something else to get a view like it's provided in the Network Tab, but with my own, JS triggered events in it (like the red / blue line).

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use Console. It gives you much more tools than simple `console.log`:

- Formatting (`console.log("%cThis will be formatted with large, blue text", "color: blue; font-size: x-large");`)

[image: Formatted message]

- Measuring time (`console.time("Array initialize"); longRunningOperation(); console.timeEnd("Array initialize");`)

[image: Measuring time]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-files/time-duration.png))</sub>

- Grouping (`console.group("Authenticating user '%s'", user); authentication(); console.groupEnd();`)

[image: Grouping]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-files/nestedgroup.png))</sub>

- Marking events on the timeline (`console.timeStamp("Adding result");`)

[image: Marking the timeline]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-files/timestamp2.png))</sub>

This should be more than enough to create readable log of custom events.
[See the official docs for more tips on using the Console.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/)

Comment: Thanks, the last thing was exactly what I was looking for!